# Is there any webhook which notifies if the ad got approved with the ad data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I read marketing-api docs . There is no webhook which triggers when the ad gets approved. Is there any way to updated us regarding the ad.

Please help.